# Bones mesh up the mesh on my character

Tags: armature

I'm making a character with an armature, but when i go to pose mode and try to change the orientation of my arm the mesh goes weird.

Here are 2 images of what is happening: (Front on view, top view)

[image: Front on view]
[image: Top view]

Anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: The weights aren't right, or the right forearm bone doesn't have "deform" enabled.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Nathan The character is made by watching a tutorial and the person said to go into pose mode with the mesh character and the armature selected, then click ctrl + P (with all selected) and then click the automatic weights button

Comment: @moonboots it is in the desc

Comment: the weight paint is bad, you need to correct it in Weight Paint mode; but do you have a reason to use such a high-poly mesh?

Comment: no i do not, it is just what the tutorial said to do. How would i correct it?

Comment: The weights aren't right.  You're having problems with the autoweights due to a combination of the vertex density at the forearm and the scale of the model.  Unparent, scale all up 10 fold about the origin, apply scale on all, and the weights will be better.  Aside, you should disable deform on "Bone" (your root).

Comment: @Nathan how do i unparent them

Comment: With a "clear parent" operation.

Comment: Thankyou @Nathan ! that worked, it was also having a fit when i tried adding an elbow to it.